# Why is Laravel's database cache driver not remembering the items I tell it to?

Tags: laravel

I am implementing relatively simple caching (database driver) on Laravel 8 and have created the cache table in the database using the suggested migration :

```
$table->string('key')->unique();
$table->text('value');
$table->integer('expiration');
```

When I use a controller to store a simple entry in the cache it works as expected :

```
Cache::put('giles', "SOMETHING", 1000);
```

I can see the entry in the cache table.

But storing more complicated things isn't having the expected result. My original code is :

```
$statistics = Statistics::all();
$emails = OutgoingEmail::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
return view('admin.home')->with(compact('emails', 'statistics'));
```

Whether I try to use the remember method :

```
$expire = 1000;
// also tried $expire = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
$statistics = Cache::remember('statistics', $expire, function() {
    return Statistics::all();
});
```

or try a more inelegant method of seeing whether the caching is set first, retrieving it if so, or retrieving the collection then using Cache::set() (code not show)...it's not storing it in the cache table.

Comment: did you try to recover `'statistics'` from cache and then check the cache table ? `$statistics = Cache::pull('statistics');` that's when the cache is saved, not at definition.

Comment: Cache::pull() retrieves and deletes, no? Cache::remember() should check if the entry exists, retrieve it if so, and store the result of the closure if not. I am looking in the database table itself to see whether the value is stored.